# Replacing Character at Specific Location in 2D Array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have two integers representing a specific location in a 2D array of characters, and I'm trying to write a method that will take those integers, use them as index locations in the array, and replace them with a new character, '.' (the method will then return the array to the main method).

Here's the (currently empty) method:

```
public static char[][] playerMoveDown(int playerPosR, int playerPosC, char[][] mazeGrid) {



}
```

I'm trying to do something to the effect of this:

```
mazeGrid[][].setCharAt(mazeGrid[playerPosR][playerPosC], '.');
```

But with something that works for a character array (since setCharAt only works for strings).  What's a simple and easy way to this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question: you want to store '.' in the array cell at coordinates playerPosR, playerPosC?

Comment: Did you try simply `mazeGrid[playerPosR][playerPosC] = '.';`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
mazeGrid[playerPosR][playerPosC] = '.';
```

Comment: That was the very first thing I tried, and *now* it suddenly works. I tried it two seconds ago and it generated about five errors. Bizarre. Anyway, problem resolved.

Comment: @ZachCox - Sometimes you can get an error message reported on one line because of a syntax error on a different line.

Comment: @ZachCox You may have used double quotes. If so, it would have given you an error because you would be trying to use a String as a char.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
public static char[][] playerMoveDown(int playerPosR, int playerPosC, char[][] mazeGrid) {
    mazeGrid[playerPosR][playerPosC] = '.';
    return mazeGrid;
}
```

I suggest getting familiar with array syntax before proceeding further...